# UseFileServer with wildcard in path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wildcard, fileserver

I have wildcards in my API-Routes, like

```
[HttpGet("api/customers/{wildcard}/add")]
```

so that I can handle multiple instances of my application and manage the endpoints with a loadbalancer that knows where to redirect based on the wildcards value. I can then use the route

```
www.example.com/api/customers/contoso/add
```

No I want the same for the UI, but the following doesn't work:

```
var root = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions()
{
    EnableDefaultFiles = true,
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
    RequestPath = new PathString("/customers/{wildcard}/app"),
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(root, "wwwroot"))
};
app.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);
```

I cannot access the static file server via

```
www.example.com/customers/contoso/interface
```

it only works if I *literally* use

```
www.example.com/customers/{wildcard}/interface
```

Do you have any idea how I can accomplish the same behaviour that successfully works for the API-routes for the static file server aswell?

Comment: did you try `*`?

Comment: * doesn't work either. I then have to use literally * in the url.

Comment: I try referring to the document for [UseFileServer Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.fileserverextensions.usefileserver?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but I did not get any information that could point to whether using the wildcard with UseFileServer() is supported. Further, I did not find any examples for the same.